# Наполнения списка возможных Command Arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Есть ли возможность для *.vcxproj указать перечень возможных аргументов для запуска приложения?

Цель: вбить 3-4 варианта запуска приложения с определённым набором аргументов и выбирать их с выпадающего списка *Command Arguments* в настройках проекта в вкладке *Debugging*

Сейчас приходится руками каждый раз писать "переключение":

- iPhone
- iPhone7
- fullscreen
  и т.д.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть расширение для Visual Studio [Set Project Command Line Arguments 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ryan113.SetProjectCommandLineArguments2015) . Судя по описанию, как раз то, что требуется:

> For example you can create a text file containing commonly used command arguments and then position your cursor on the line you want and this command will copy that line of text into the startup project's command line arguments property

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!